# Ubuntu not accessible from Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

i was using Ubuntu in the last two months over the Virtual Box. I installed so many programs and saved alot of files. All of a sudden when i click to VB i get the messagethat Ubuntu is not accessible and the following:

```
Runtime error opening 'C:\Users\absolution\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Linux\Ubuntu Linux.vbox' for reading: -102(File not found.).
F:\tinderbox\win-5.1\src\VBox\Main\src-server\MachineImpl.cpp[745] (long __cdecl Machine::i_registeredInit(void)).
Fehlercode:
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Komponente:
MachineWrap
Interface:
IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}
```

Can anybody help me recover my Ubuntu ?

For some unknown reason i could't ask a qusetion in the VB Forum. I am sorry to ask it here.
Many thanks.

Comment: if you didn't lost your disks, just create another VB Machine, adding these to new machine.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by disks. How can i find them ? The job i have done in Ubuntu is enormous. How can such a thing happen ? How secure is VB ? Please try to answer some of these questions.

Comment: A VB Machine is a folder with several components. Main ones are *.vbox and *.vdi files. It's possible you lose .vbox file. Look for *.vdi files, these are logical disks. If you create a newer VB Machine, can attach these disks you have from existing VB. Open `C:\Users\absolution\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Linux\`, you will find *.vdi file there.

Comment: This would be better asked on http://superuser.com as you have VB installed on Windows and that is what has the issue, not Ubuntu.

Comment: I found the .vdi file. How can i then attach these disks to the new VB Machine ? I am new with VB so any support would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When creating a new machine, you have the option to create a new drive or use an existing one, choose to use an existing one.

Comment: I could succesfully follow your recommandations but what i get after launching Ubuntu from the new machine is: Fatal! No bootable medium found! System halted. What does this mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Today, I have also gone through above issue and VirtualBox was saying inaccessible and above message.

In little bit of googling I come across one solution which has resolved my issue.

Steps:
1- Navigate to the folder of vbox which is not found on your machine Like in your case it is C:\Users\absolution\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Linux
2- Just observe the following files.

1. .vdi file
2. Ubuntu Linux.vbox-prev
3. Ubuntu Linux.vbox-temp

Now you can open any of these two .vbox-prev or .vbox-temp file and now go and save as Ubuntu Linux.vbox. While keeping these two files.

3- Now again navigate to VirtualBox and Click on the refresh icon. Now the status will change to Power Off.
4- Click on start and access your virtual machine and enjoy your work.